# Close MvxMasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, mvvmcross

I have a simple application presentation:

[image]

When I run the application, I check to see if the user entered, and then I load the main page, if not, then I load the login page.

But when the user logout, I need to close MasterDetailPage (MvxMasterDetailPage) and load a simple NavigationPage (MvxContentPage), because I do not need the humburger menu on LoginPage.

**How can I close MvxMasterDetailPage?**

Answer (score 1):

Yea, i found an answer:
In LoginPage.xaml.cs add this attribute: `[MvxContentPagePresentation(NoHistory = true)]`

Here is the full class:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[MvxContentPagePresentation(NoHistory = true, Animated = true)]
public partial class LoginPage : MvxContentPage<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginPage ()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```